# Trying to determine how to run Windows app on Wine in command line mode

Tags: linux, windows-services, windows, wine

We have written a program which needs to run all the time that has a user interface (but is not necessary for running) under WINE on Linux.   Want to sort of treat like Windows Service.

We have tried numerous options found in various places on the internet.  Options like --nogui or /nogui but it does not appear to work.

Has anyone done this and been successful before?

Comment: Does `needs to run all the time` mean _continuously_, _repeatedly back-to-back, with a short/constant pause between end and start, with a short/constant delay between starts_ or something else, entirely?

Comment: It means that once the application starts it will stay running (but that is really the app itself).  The application just doesn't seem to run at all.  I guess I need to try to generate some log information to help gather error messages (if any are occurring).

Comment: Do you get any (negative) feed-back trying to start the process? If not: can you truss/strace the start?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
screen wine myapp.exe &
```

Your application need to run an infinite cycle so do not terminate.

Regards